# Need MySQL query for data cleanup

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. One table with travel distances

```
create table routes
(
  slat int,
  slng int,
  dlat int,
  dlng int,
  distance int
);
```

One table with sites

```
create table sites
( 
  id int,
  name varchar(100),
  lat int,
  lng int
);
```

And one table with technicians

```
create table fse
(
  id int,
  name varchar(100),
  lat int,
  lng int
);
```

The travel distance table is filled dynamically from google API request. So if there is a new site or a new technician, all the new travel distances are requested by google and store into the route table

Of cause it could also happen, that a customer or a technician leaves. In that case the entries in the distance table stay in the database even if they are no longer used.

I want to remove this unused rows in the table. So I am looking for a query which is deleting all “not existing” lat/long combinations in the sites/fse table like written in the comment in this fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwF1iyZ7nn8rnDcE8Wstch/0

I could write this query by myself but the only solution I have is using very much sub selects. But I am wondering if there isn’t a more efficient way and hope one of the sql professionals here can help?

Answer (score 0):

This query that should work:

```
delete from routes where concat (slat,'|', slng) not in (
  select concat(lat ,'|', lng) from sites 
  union  select concat(lat,'|',lng) from fse
) ;
```

it  selects all record from the tables `sites` and `fse` and deletes rows from routes where no record found in the subquery. The concat of both columns is needed, because `in` can only handle one column. The `|` is only to separate the values

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwF1iyZ7nn8rnDcE8Wstch/1)

Comment: MySQL can work on tuples, so the concatenation isn't needed: `... (slat, slng) IN (SELECT lat, lng FROM ...`.

Comment: DB fiddle doesn't allow it

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mDtZVufrk6ZGUPCPXucbWg/1 ?

Comment: Oh and also as a side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL and MariaDB accept that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL or MariaDB versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: @stickybit, Totally agree, and also MySQL and MariaDB do change the meaning of double quotes depending on the SQL mode option. So even on current versions, your code using double-quotes as string delimiters can break without warning.